Is there any counterpart of replacement tokens available in other Knowledge system, in Salesforce Knowledge?
My client needs to migrate articles from old system to Salesforce Knowledge.
In the source system, there is a special term of replacement token.
There is a dynamic text in articles like {{REPLACEMENT_TOKEN.locale}} which is being dynamically substituted by actual html code defined for that token.
I have seen that Salesforce provides option to insert Quick Text into Salesforce Article, but it works in the different way.
Instead of having dynamic text linkage, it just insert the current value of Quick Text and when Quick Text is later changed, this change is not reflected in the corresponding article.
Is there any standard functionality or counterpart for the notion of dynamic token replacement in Salesforce Knowledge?
Is there any markup or syntax in knowledge articles to dynamically refer to Quick Text?
